# Retain NULL value from BIT

Tags: sql, mysql

I have column testColumn1(bit, null) and I`m trying to set this value to testColumn2(int, null).

Original value testColumn1(bit, null) = NULL

For some reason

```
SET
    testColumn2 = CASE WHEN ref.testColumn1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ref.testColumn1 END,
```

this code saves NULL as 0.
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Pleasse show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement for the source and destination tables.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that it's actually `testColumn2(int, not null)`

Comment: You don't need the `CASE` expression. Just `SET testColumn2 = testColumn1` should work and preserve `NULL`. `NULL` is weird in comparisons, but it acts normally in assignments.

Comment: also, what does SHOW WARNINGS show immediately after the update?